# How to pass a file URLS in the document directory when a UICollectionViewCells are selected

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, swift3

I am working on an app that can merge multiple single page pdfs into one multiple page pdf and I have them displayed in a `UICollectionView`. I put the contents of the `.documentDirectory` into a `[String]` for setting the data source for the `UICollectionView`. Everything displays fine but I am having trouble passing each file URL into an array that I can use in a function I modified for my use to merge the documents. I tried passing them with the use of

```
let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForSelectedItem
```

This isn't working since it is only passing the `indexPath` `Int` values, as well this has casting issues.

This is the function for merging the multiple selected pdfs.

```
func joinPDF(_ listOfPaths: [Any]) {
    var pdfPathOutput = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    pdfPathOutput = pdfPathOutput.appending("/iScan_pdf_\(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)).pdf")
    let pdfURLOutput: CFURL? = (URL(fileURLWithPath: pdfPathOutput) as CFURL?)
    var numberOfPages: Int = 0
    // Create the output context
    let writeContext = CGContext(pdfURLOutput!, mediaBox: nil, nil)
    for source in listOfPaths {
        let pdfURL: CFURL? = (URL(fileURLWithPath: source as! String) as CFURL?)
        //file ref
        let pdfRef: CGPDFDocument? = CGPDFDocument(pdfURL!)
        numberOfPages = pdfRef!.numberOfPages
        // Loop variables
        var page: CGPDFPage? = nil
        var mediaBox = CGRect.zero
        // Read the first PDF and generate the output pages
        // Finalize the output file
        print("GENERATING PAGES FROM PDF 1 (%@)...")
        for i in 1...numberOfPages {
            page = pdfRef?.page(at: i)
            mediaBox = page!.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
            writeContext!.beginPage(mediaBox: &mediaBox)
            writeContext!.drawPDFPage(page!)
            writeContext!.endPage()
        }

    }
    writeContext!.closePDF()
}
```

I just need a little help putting the selected cells file URLs into an array.  I created the `UICollectionView` datasource like so.

```
 titles = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: documentsDirectories)
```

titles is a `[String]` then I have another var called images it is a `[UIImage]`. I run for in loop to get the images from the titles and then set the datasource like so

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.item]
```

I have a function that creates a thumbnail image from the pdfs to display them in the `imageView` In function didSelectItemAt I have it set up like so.

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if selected == true {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        cell?.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

    }
}
```

This is where I need to enter the items into an array just not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: I will when I get it all worked out still having issues and haven't had time to mess with it much today

Answer (score 0):

Basic logic should be something like this.

1. you make an arrayOfUrls to hold selected page url
2. when user select or deselects add or remove urls through arrayOfUrls
3. when user clicks done button call join with arrayOfUrls

There are better ways but with above info I can help you this much.
Hope this helps...

**Updated answer after question update**

Having multiple arrays defeats the reason of OOP.. below is the way to do this

make a class with needed variables…say you need image, urlOfPDF and isSelected…

```
class PDFPage : NSObject {
    var title : String = ""
    var imageURL : String = "" //you can use uiimage object instead
    var urlOfPDF : NSNumber = -1
    var isSelected : Bool = false
}
```

before you reload data in collection view do the mapping and add all objects of PDFPage in an array (say allPDFArray)…

something like this…

```
for (int i = 0, i<titles.count, i++){
    var page: PDFPage = PDFPage()
    page.title = titles[i] 
    page.imageURL = set image for above title[i] here
    page.urlOfPDF = set url for above title[i] here
    page. isSelected = false
    allPDFArray.add(page)
}
```

now you have all you need locally

in cellForItemAt

```
let page = allPDFArray[indexpath.row] //now you have your all data in page obj
cell.imageView.image = page.image //or image url
cell.title.text = page.title
cell.isSelected can be used to highlight cell…you will need it as reloading cell will show you wrong results when you scroll
```

Similarly in didSelectItemAt

```
let page = allPDFArray[indexpath.row]
page.isSelected = page.isSelected
if page.isSelected then highlight
```

once user clicks done…
just go through all elements of allPDFArray and see which are selected and make an array here which you can send to joinPDF

Comment: I understand that I need to create an arrayOfUrls for the selected cells but I don't know how I should go about doing it

Comment: it should be easier to understand if I have code to see how u have implemented collection view...
collection view has didSelectItemAtIndexPath delegate, with indexpath you can decide which url to add in array and which to remove

Comment: Ok so it seems you have made an array of images which you map according to titles, is this correct? can you make an array of all pdf urls?

Comment: Yes thats correct. And that is simple with the use of   `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)` but how do I pass them from the indexPath

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137423/discussion-between-jjaaxx44-and-carpenterblood).